# Regex: Match string until character possibly appears

Tags: regex

Current regex I am using:

```
\[QUOTE=(.*?)\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/QUOTE\]
```

Example text:

```
[QUOTE=Me;1202]Hey there[/QUOTE]
```

I want $1 to match "Me" and $2 to match "Hey there".

At the moment $1 matches "Me;1202"

Plus, if I have the example text of

```
[QUOTE=Me]Hey there[/QUOTE]
```

it should still match "Me".

How do I do that?

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: How should you treat nested quotes ? RegEx are maybe not suited for that, you can look for a proper bbcode parser. `[QUOTE=Me;1202]Hey [QUOTE=you;1202]Hello world[/QUOTE] there[/QUOTE]` That is a very possible case, since in forums you can see prople quoting other posts that have already quotes

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex with negated character classes:

```
/\[QUOTE=([^\];]*)[^\]]*\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/QUOTE\]/ig
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BqB63W/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[^\];]*`: Match 0 or more characters that are not `;` and `]`
- `[^\]]*`: Match 0 or more characters that are not `]`

Comment: This one treats wrongly nested quotes `[QUOTE=Me;1202]Hey [QUOTE=you;1202]Hello world[/QUOTE] there[/QUOTE]` gives a partial content for quote : `Hey [QUOTE=you;1202]Hello world`

Comment: No I am trying to solve nested tag problems with regex and neither it is asked here by OP otherwise I wouldn't have posted an answer.

Comment: bbcode nested quotes tags are often meet in forums. But yeah, I totally agree with you, there is no point using regex to parse nested nodes

Comment: How could I approach this then? Using either php or JS.

Comment: I have already posted a working solution, does it not work for you?